# creating a quicktime file from a keynote with embedded mov files then to mp4 for ipad

Tags: ipad, quicktime, mp4, mov, keynote

I am trying to create a quicktime file from a keynote presentation that has mov movies embedded in them.  I have used the "record slideshow" option and then created a quicktime file from that, but the mov file that result has issues with the embedded movies. The first two show up but the middle two have a black screen.  the ultimate goal is to convert them into mp4 so that the whole presentation can play on the ipad.

Any insight is greatly appreciated

E

Answer (score 1):

Select play to click into the inspector of your video files.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the object (video) has the inspector option START MOVIE